# Bash script to check if FileSystem is ext4

Tags: bash

im trying to write script to check if filesystem is ext4 or not before it mount. I have defined variables. It looks like this

```
fs=$(fdisk -l | awk '{print $1,$NF}' | grep "/dev/sda1")
            DEV=/dev/sda1
            fs1=${fs#*$DEV}

            if [[ -e $diskL && $fs1 != "ext4"  ]]; then
                    echo "Bad fs"
            else
                    echo "Good fs"
            fi
```

And it does not work

Answer (score 0):

The value you get from your first line is not the filesystem type. You can try using `mount` to get types and avoid using root privileges (`fdisk` requires them). `mount` without options gives you full information including types of all mounted devices.

Get the line of `mount` response with specific device with `grep` and get rid of unnecessary info with `awk` or `sed`.

`fs=$(mount | grep "/dev/sda2" | sed "s/.*type \(.*\) .*/\1/")`

Comment: Okay, my bad. when Im doing first line, Im getting Linux (as type). So if I get other type i want script to tell me 'its bad type'.
I do this script before mounting disk.

Comment: To make it clear: You want to check the file system on a disk, without mounting the disk? If this is the case, make it clear in your question, not in a comment.

Comment: @simspoon To get the filesystem type of all devices, including unmounted devices, use `lsblk -f | grep sda2 | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: Thanks to everyone. @Alloces This is what i wanted